# How to format a number in American and European style in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, formatting

I want to be able to format a number (of type double) in American and European style. Depending on user's choice the number 123123123.456 should be formatted as either:

- 123,123,123.456  // American format
- 123.123.123,456  // European format

Another requirement is to be able to set the number of decimals. I believe I could use `double.ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)` and put `"F2"` as the `format` but msdn doesn't seem to tell much about `IFormatProvider` apart for explaining that I could implement it myself.

```
double x = 123123123.456
IFormatProvider myFormatProvider = whatToDo ?
x.ToString("F2", myFormatProvider); // I need 2 decimal digits hence F2
```

Are there any premade number IFormatProvider objects I could use for that purpose? Or maybe there are other solutions and I'm  going wrong way?

Comment: I'm in Europe (UK) and we would write 123,123,123.456

Comment: Just display the number as a string, and format the string, based on the user's preference. This question shows a complete lack of research before hand.

Comment: @LeeTaylor: well, you Brits can hardly be called real Europeans, can you? ;-)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/78175/International-Number-Formats This gives a good list of which countries use what.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
IFormatProvider myFormatProvider = new CultureInfo("en-us").NumberFormat;
```

or

```
IFormatProvider myFormatProvider = new CultureInfo("fr").NumberFormat;
```

(just using France as the culture here, but it could be almost any European country).

Answer (score 1):

IFormatProvider can be a CultureInfo:

```
double x = 123123123.456
System.Globalization.CultureInfo EnglishCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-EN");
x.ToString("F2",EnglishCulture);
```

or

```
x.ToString("F2",EnglishCulture.NumberFormat);
```